# How To Edit Excel Using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, hash, cryptography

In Python, I am trying to make a program.

I have an excel file containing a list of passwords. The program needs to read the file line by line. For each password, python hashes it in MD5, and then writes the hashed value into excel next to the password.

However, I'm really stuck and would appreciate any help.

Here are the first 20 lines of the excel sheet:

[Top 20 Passwords](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Pbf5.png)

Currently, this is what I have done:

```python
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

columns = defaultdict(list) # each value in each column is appended to a list

with open('allpass.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f) # read rows into a dictionary format
    for row in reader: # read a row as {column1: value1, column2: value2,...}
        for (k,v) in row.items(): # go over each column name and value 
            columns[k].append(v) # append the value into the appropriate list
                                 # based on column name k

print(columns['Password'])
```

This prints out all the passwords. I need to figure out how to write to excel.

Comment: Agree that you need to provide more info on topic, but to read excel file you can use `pandas` framework, especially [`pandas.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

Comment: *how to write to excel* -> https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5Dwrite+to+excel

Comment: maybe someone can find the best matching duplicate target in that search above.

Comment: Do you need to read and write Excel files, or csv files as in your example?

Comment: Only Excel Files